# How to dynamically extend or compose a Yup schema

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

Say I have a `Yup.string()` to begin with.

Then, at some point, like in a loop, I wanna add `required` rule to it, effectively:

`Yup.string().required('This field is required')`.

And maybe then add some `.email` check too.

I have tried this way but didn't seem to work:

```
function validationSchemaConstructor(question) {
  const schema = Yup.string();

  question.validation_rules.forEach(rule => {
    if ("is_required" in rule) {
      schema.required("Hey man nice shot");
    }
  });

  return schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah my mistake- I need to assign the `schema` again cuz chaining in general works by returning the object again:

```
function validationSchemaConstructor(question) {
  let schema = Yup.string();

  question.validation_rules.forEach(rule => {
    if ("is_required" in rule) {
      schema = schema.required("Hey man nice shot");  // mistake here!
    }
  });

  // un-comment to test dynamically adding additional rule
  // schema = schema.email("email plesss");

  return schema;
}
```

Though not sure if I should use the `clone()` somewhere.

Please advice if there's a better way :)